# Hadoop use KeyValueTextInputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I use hadoop 1.0.1 to do some project and I want to make my input .txt file be the "key" and 
"value" which I need, like:

If I have a `test.txt` file and the file content is

> 1, 10 10

I think I can use "KeyValueTextInputFormat" and make "," be the separation symbol, so after input, the *key* is *"1"* and the *value* is *"10 10"*.

But, the result I got is all the information is key, the value is empty. I dont know where is the problem.

Please give me some help, thanks!

This is the example code:

```
public class WordCount{
    public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{  

        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(value, value);
            context.write(key, key);
        }   
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line",",");
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
          System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        KeyValueTextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The separator can be specified under the attribute name `mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator`, The default separator is the tab character `('\t')`. 
So in your case change the line `conf.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line",",");` 
 to

```
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator",",");
```

and that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

i have just tried that `KeyValueTextInputFormat` is taked key and values if they have a tab between them, other wise it will take the complete line as a key, and there will nothing in value.

so we have to use `1   10,10` in place of `1, 10 10`

Comment: Yes you are right. But you can change the default seperator of KeyValueTextInputFormat and acheive the target http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/can-we-change-default-key-value-input.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using the stuff correctly.

[Link](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/09/can-we-change-default-key-value-input.html)
While running your current code the output is like

```
 10 10   10 10
1   1
```

why is it like this is because

You are emiting 2 key-value pair.

First key-value pair is *value   value*
and second key-value pair is *key   key*

which is the right one
*value is 10 
and key is 1*

```
public class WordCount{
    public class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{  

        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write("key", key);              //prints key as 1
            context.write("value", value);          //prints value as 10 10
            System.out.println(key.toString());
            System.out.println(value.toString());
        }   
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

The input file is converted into key value pairs and map function will be called for all such pairs.
Now in case of your example,the input to map will be some key(which will probably be 1,since it is the line number in the file)and most importantly your value will be 1,10 10.

Now you can output anything from your mapper which will go to the reducer class's reduce function only after swapping and sorting of all the output from mapper.

So if you output context.write(value) from your mapper and same from your reducer you will get unique lines from all your files.

I don't think I have explained what you want,but this is the basic thing that happens in Hadoop Map-Reduce.